# Filter nested arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const array = [{ "title": "Carros", "data" : [{ "nome": "Mustang" }, {"nome": "Camaro"}]}];
   
let filteredArray = array
  .filter((element) => 
element.data.some((subElement) => subElement.nome == "Mustang"))
  .map(element => {
return Object.assign({}, element, {nome : element.data.filter(subElement => subElement.nome == "Mustang")});
  });
```

The `filteredArray` is always returning the same array but with a child `"nome"` element.

What I want is to search for "mus" or "tang" or "mustang" or "mu" and return:

```
[{ "title": "Carros", "data" : [{ "nome": "Mustang" }]}];
```

the same if I have another column like:

```
[{ "title": "Carros", "data" : [{ "nome": "Mustang" }]},
{ "title": "Motos", "data" : [{ "nome": "Yamaha }]}];
```

and the search for "mustang" needs to return:

```
const array = [{ "title": "Carros", "data" : [{ "nome": "Mustang" }]},
{ "title": "Motos", "data" : [] }];
```

I need to maintain the same structure but only change the nested "data".

Comment: Will you have more objects in the main `array`? Like other categories like motorcycles or bikes? Or is it just the one `Carros` object?

Answer (score 0):

```
  let array = [{ title: "Carros", data: [{ nome: "Mustang" }, {nome: "Camaro"}]}];
function Query(data) {


    let newData = [...array[0].data].filter((x,i) => x.nome === data)
    array = [{...array[0],data: newData }]
    console.log(array);
}
Query("Mustang")
```

I am not familiar with typescript but here is some vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [{ "title": "Carros", "data" : [{ "nome": "Mustang" }]},
{ "title": "Motos", "data" : [{ "nome": "Yamaha" }]}];

function filterStuff(array, deepname) {
    return array.map(element => ({
        ...element,
        data: element.data.filter(deepElement => deepElement.nome === deepname)
    }))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filterStuff(array, "Mustang")));

// Output:
// [{"title":"Carros","data":[{"nome":"Mustang"}]},{"title":"Motos","data":[]}]
```

This gives you a method to call to filter by that deep element, and is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Great bro, it works, but how use with includes(), because im using a searchbar that search from length > 2 like: when search for Mus, it will return all Mus, like Mustang

Comment: @VélcisRibeiro, just change `deepElement.nome === deepname` to `deepElement.nome.includes(deepname)`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to use Lodash+[Deepdash](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep), then you can do:

```
// filter by Mustang(no empty categories)
let res = _.filterDeep(data,(v)=>_.includes(v.nome,"Mus"),{tree:{children:"data"}});

// get all empty categories
let structure = _.omitDeep(data,/\.data.+/);

_.merge(structure,res);
console.log(structure);
```

Here is a [Codepen for this](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/jJGVQX?editors=0010)